# Function ActiveX item scope

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX combobox on "Sheet 1" of my Excel document.
When I want to create an event function of this combobox the function is created into the "Sheet 1" window of my VBA-project / Excel documentt.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 MsgBox ("qmdlkfj")
End Sub
```

But I want to move it into my "Module 1" window (where all my code is written).
Is this possible or not ? When I move the function in the "Module 1" or even into the "ThisWorkbook" window no event is triggered and thus no messagebox is shown.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How would code in a standard module know which ActiveX control from which sheet it should handle?

Comment: Avoid the use of ActiveX controls on worksheet. Use the Formcontrols. You can tie them up with code in module

Comment: @GSerg that's what I was asking myself too :)

Comment: you can Code in Module1 what procedure's argument is "Control" Or "Combobox"

Comment: @Sacru2red: For an `ActiveX` control, I am afraid you can not. You only can assign a `Sub` in case of a `Form` control. For ActiveX control you must write a procedure, but it must be called by an event which is mandatory to be in the sheet module where the control exists...

Comment: The reason I used the ActiveX combobox is because only this item seems to be "programmable" to have an autocomplete function, or this is not true ?

Comment: @smirnoff103 The event handler has to be in the sheet that contains the control. But you can have the actual code in a module, and call the module handler procedure from the event handler in the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

you can Code in Module1 what procedure's argument is "Control" Or "Combobox"

example my Code

```
Public Sub setComboValue(targetCb As ComboBox, xValue As String, findCol As Long)
    Dim hasDataIndex As Long: hasDataIndex = -1
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To targetCb.ListCount - 1
        If xValue = targetCb.List(i, findCol) Then
            hasDataIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    If hasDataIndex <> -1 Then
        targetCb.ListIndex = hasDataIndex
    Else
        targetCb.Value = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```